# Counting Sort implementation

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception, counting-sort

Hello I am having difficulty implementing a counting sort method in java. I believe the problem comes from the last two loops I have in the method. I am getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception : 8. I believe this comes from my second to last for loop when at index 5 the value is 8 but I am not sure how to resolve this. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

In my code k is the highest value in the input array.

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] arrayOne = {0,1,1,3,4,5,3,0};
    int [] output = Arrays.copyOf(arrayOne, arrayOne.length);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayOne));
    countingSort(arrayOne, output, 5);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(output));

}

public static void countingSort(int[] input, int[] output , int k){
    int [] temp = Arrays.copyOf(input, k+1);

    for (int i = 0; i <= k; i++){
        temp[i] = 0;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j <= input.length - 1; j++){
        temp[input[j]] = temp[input[j]] + 1;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++){
        temp[i] = temp[i] + temp[i-1];
    }

    for (int j = input.length; j >= 1; j--){
        output[temp[input[j]]] = input[j];
        temp[input[j]] = temp[input[j]] - 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try changing `for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++)` to `for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)`

Comment: for (int j = input.length; j >= 1; j--)  may also need to be changed to for (int j = input.length -1; j >= 1; j--)

Comment: Thanks for the response! This doesn't resolve the out of bounds exception, I am getting this exception in the last for loop second line. The first for loop is there to initialize each value in the temp array to 0.

Comment: please check out the code in my updated answer, it should work!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the first loop because the array `temp` lenght is 6 and you are doing 7 interations in there.

So at the end of the `for` it is trying to do `temp[6]=0` and the last position of your array is `temp[5]`.

To fix this change your first loop to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++){
```

In the last loop you will get the same exception cause `input[8]` doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for the response! This doesn't resolve the out of bounds exception, I am getting this exception in the last for loop second line. The first for loop is there to initialize each value in the temp array to 0. That loop is only iterating 5 times because the original value of k is 5.

Answer (score 0):

this may help but try using the Arraya.sort() method.
e.g:

```
//A Java program to sort an array of integers in ascending order.
// A sample Java program to sort an array of integers 
// using Arrays.sort(). It by default sorts in 
// ascending order 
import java.util.Arrays; 

public class SortExample 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        // Our arr contains 8 elements 
        int[] arr = {13, 7, 6, 45, 21, 9, 101, 102}; 

        Arrays.sort(arr); 

        System.out.printf("Modified arr[] : %s", 
                          Arrays.toString(arr)); 
    } 
}
```

example is a snippet from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arrays-sort-in-java-with-examples/

Comment: Answers should not rely on links for the bulk of the content. Links can go dead, or the content on the other side can be changed to no longer answer the question. Please edit your answer to include the information you have linked to.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class CountingSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] input = {0,1,1,3,4,5,3,0};
        int[] output = new int[input.length];
        int k = 5; // k is the largest number in the input array
        System.out.println("before sorting:");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(input)); 
        output = countingSort(input, output, k);
        System.out.println("after sorting:");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(output));
    }

    public static int[] countingSort(int[] input, int[] output, int k) {
        int counter[] = new int[k + 1]; 
        for (int i : input) { counter[i]++; } 
        int ndx = 0; 
        for (int i = 0; i < counter.length; i++) {
            while (0 < counter[i]) { 
                output[ndx++] = i;
                counter[i]--; 
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

Above code is adapted from: http://www.java67.com/2017/06/counting-sort-in-java-example.html

Comment: Answers should not rely on links for the bulk of the content. Links can go dead, or the content on the other side can be changed to no longer answer the question. Please edit your answer to include the information you have linked to.

Comment: I have edited my answer, thanks for your suggestion @mypetition

Answer (score 0):

As per algorithm following implementation, I have prepared for the count sort technique

```
public static int[] countSort(int elements[]) {
    int[] sorted = new int[elements.length+1];
    int[] range = new int[getMax(elements)+1];
    for(int i=0;i<range.length;i++) {
        range[i] = getCount(i, elements);
        try {
            range[i] = range[i]+range[i-1];
        }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ae) {
            continue;
        }
    }       

    for(int i=0;i<elements.length;i++) {
        sorted[range[elements[i]]] = elements[i];
        range[elements[i]] = range[elements[i]]-1;
    }       
    return sorted;
}

public static int getCount(int value,int[] elements) {
    int count = 0;
    for(int element:elements) {
        if(element==value) count++;
    }
    return count;
}

public static int getMax(int elements[]) {
    int max = elements[0];
    for(int i=0;i<elements.length;i++) {
        if(max<elements[i]) {
            max = elements[i];
        }           
    }
    return max;
}
```

Please review and let me know if any feedback and it is more helpful.
Note :
Non-negative no won't support in the above implementation.
don't use 0th index of the sorted array.